# Stop/start window resize when viewport width reaches some value

Tags: javascript, jquery

### The goal

If user's viewport reaches some value, I need to stop or start:

```
jQuery(window).on('resize'){ // ... }
```

### The scenario

Let's suppose that we have the following array (in JavaScript):

```
var ranges = [1024, 1280];
```

I'm using `jQuery(window).on('resize'){}` with some ifs inside to do things when user's viewport raches a width between the values set by `ranges`' array.

But I just want to run those "things" when the viewport is out or in range with the widths from the array. I mean, `jQuery(window).on('resize'){}` should stop to run when the user's viewport is between `1024px` x `1280px`of width, but its need to wake up when the viewport is out of range to do another thing that I want.

### Playground

To have a better comprehension of the problem, **open your console** and [take a look in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6L83/).

You'll see that the console prints 
"*Hi*" for each time that jsFiddle JavaScript's Window has its width changed, and I want to display it once.

***Oh my god, are you stupid?! Your script is wrong because nothing is printing here.*** Calm down, fella! jsFiddle doesn't interpret `$(window)` as your browser's window. To run the function, you should to resize result window. Look:
[image]

### What I'm expecting, actually

Based on the above's script, I want to see `Hi!` just when the viewport enters in some width between `1024px` x `1280px` — *once*. When the viewport is outside, nothing happens, but when viewport enters in the specified width again, prints `Hi!` — *again* and *once*.

### What have I tried?

Actually, I'm stuck. My mind can't think in the solution — *I need a light!*

### Doubts? I haven't made clear enough?

Comment your question, please!

### Duplicated?

Post the link or marks as duplicate — I didn't saw any similar topic like this before (sorry for this).

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be working correctly, I only get Hi! when the window is between the range.

Comment: Yep, working perfectly !! BUT ! "you should to move JavaScript's window" NO ! You are moving the result window in fact. Resize the JS windows by top or bottom, nothing will happens ;)

Comment: @dSquared My bad, friend — I just want to see "Hi!" once.

Comment: @TCHdvlp You're right. But this is just a detail, hah.

Comment: Just red the comment for dSquared. What are you trying to do is very similar to a state mechanism, with 2 states. State inside borders, state outside. What's the best way to save and/or modify the state of something. I suggest to use a variable like `var state=0 //inside`. Each time you are resizing the window, check for the state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to keep track of the state.  Here's a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/5ZP5g/)** that I think does what you want:

```
var isInRange = (function() {
    var test = function() {
        return $(window).width() >= 1024 && $(window).width() <= 1280;
    };
    var current = test();
    return function() {
        if (test()) {
            if (!current) {
                current = true;
                console.log('Hi!');
            }
        } else {
            current = false;
        }
    }
}())

$(window).on('resize', isInRange);
```

---

### Update

Okay, after all these comments, I'm really not happy with the code as written.  Here's **[another version](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/UZ5GH/)** of the same ideas, cleaning up some of the code and adding the onExit functionality too:

```
var isInRange = (function() {
    var $window = $(window);
    var test = function() {
        var ww = $window.width();
        return ww >= 1024 && ww <= 1280;
    };
    var inRange = test();
    var onEnter = function() {
        console.log("Hi");
    };
    var onExit = function() {
        console.log("Bye");
    };
    return function() {
        test() ? (!inRange && (inRange = true) && onEnter())
               : ((inRange && onExit()) || (inRange = false));
    };
}())

$(window).on('resize', isInRange);
```

It's a little more clean, a little more organized, and slightly more efficient.  But nothing really substantive has changed.

Comment: You visibly got the same idea. I think that confirms this is the good answer. ;)

Comment: Scott! Your code worked perfectly, too. I gave you +1, but I didn't accepted the answer because `dSquared`'s code seems a little bit more organized for me. No problem for you, right? Anyway, thank you very very much! You inspired me some ideas! Thanksss!

Comment: Not at all.  I threw this together in a hurry.

Comment: Actually, *organized* isn't the term. Both answers seem pretty well organized to me. Scott's is just a little more sophisticated, in that he uses a closure to execute a wrapper function that returns the function that gets executed.

Comment: @Robusto: that was only to keep the state variable out of global scope.  Since I had it, I was able to make a test function in that same closure too.  I find this cleaner, and therefore perhaps slightly more organized, but it's really a matter of preference.  I certainly didn't spend any time on cleaning up the code.  (That state variable should not be called "current"; I definitely should not call `$(window)` on each call or `$(window).width()` twice per resize.)

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use a flag to keep track of the state, I've updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6L83/3/) as follows:

```
var inRange;

function isInRange() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 1024 && $(window).width() <= 1280){
        if (!inRange){
            inRange = true;
            console.log('Hi!');
        }   
    } else {
        inRange = false;
    }
}

$(window).on('resize', isInRange).trigger('resize');
```

**EDIT**

To show a different message only once depending on whether the window is inside or outside the set range, simply keep track of two states with flags like so:

```
var inRange, outsideRange;

function isInRange() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 1024 && $(window).width() <= 1280){
        outsideRange = false;

        if (!inRange){
            inRange = true;
            console.log('Hi!');
        }
    } else {
        inRange = false;

        if (!outsideRange){
            outsideRange = true;
            console.log('Bye!');
        }
    }
}

$(window).on('resize', isInRange).trigger('resize');
```

Here is the updated [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6L83/7/).

I hope this helps!

Comment: And what if I want to show `Bye!` when the range reaches outside?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Bye! only once as well?

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Take a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

**just tell it when to go**

```
var min=1024, max=1280, go;//values
$(window).on('resize', function() {//on resize
    var ww = $(window).width();//get window width
    if (go && ww >= min && ww <= max) {//go & in range
        console.log('Hi!');//print 'Hi!'
        go = false;//!go
    } else if (!go && (ww<min || ww>max)) {//!go & out of range
        console.log('Bye!');//print 'Bye!'
        go = true;//go
    }
});
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/zP39t/

Comment: Definitely a good idea to cache `$(window).width()` even for the two calls.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: I was going to suggest that in your answer. :)

Comment: it's better than calling it potentially 4 times on every resize event; that would be craziness!